# How to extract more than one table present in a PDF file with tabula in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-munging, tabula

If only one table is present in a PDF file then that can be simply extracted using the code

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df = read_pdf(r"C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\Desktop\pdf_file.pdf")
```

But if there is more than one table present in a PDF file I am unable to extract those tables because it's only extracting the first one.

Answer (score 3):

There? Hope the below code will be helpful, still I didn't test it with large tables. Let me know is there any scenario which could affect or fail with this code. I'm new to python so that I can improve my knowledge :)

```
import os
from tabula import wrapper
os.chdir("E:/Documents/myPy/")
tables = wrapper.read_pdf("MyPDF.pdf",multiple_tables=True,pages='all',encoding='utf-8',spreadsheet=True)

i=1
for table in tables:
    table.columns = table.iloc[0]
    table = table.reindex(table.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
    table.columns.name = None
    #To write Excel
    table.to_excel('output'+str(i)+'.xlsx',header=True,index=False)
    #To write CSV
    table.to_csv('output'+str(i)+'.csv',sep='|',header=True,index=False)
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Even when using the tabula-py wrapper you can use all the same options as can be found on the Tabula Java Docs.

In your case you can simply add `pages = "all"`:

```py
from tabula import read_pdf
df = read_pdf(r"C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\Desktop\pdf_file.pdf", pages = "all")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your PDF has multiple tables, you can use `multiple_tables=true` option.

Answer (score 0):

using `multiple_tables=true` parameter in the `read_pdf` will solve the issue

Example:

```py
from tabula import wrapper
df = wrapper.read_pdf("sample.pdf",multiple_tables=True)
```

Now the `read_pdf` is in wrapper, so we need to import that and use as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have the same structure(i.e, have the same table structure and the same relative position) in all pages of pdf, then you can set pages='all' to get the correct result.

If not, you may need to iterate all pages to parser the pdf.

There are a [documention](https://aegis4048.github.io/parse-pdf-files-while-retaining-structure-with-tabula-py) that explains it in detail.